# Pivot control showing one Pivot but registering taps in another

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a todolist app which features several `ListBox` controls inside separate `PivotItems` within a `Pivot` control. If I navigate to another page, and return with the back button, the displayed `Pivot` is unresponsive. However, activity on it (Scrolling, Tapping etc) appears to affect the *next* `Pivot` over, ie the selectedIndex + 1;

It sounds very much like a bug in the `Pivot` control, but maybe I'm doing something wrong? Here's the code for my pivot control.

```
[code updated, see below]
```

I don't think the code of the page I'm navigating to is important as the behaviour happens with the back button

**Some other important info:**

- On the very *first* `PivotItem` (index 0), the error **does not** occur.
- On the very *last* `PivotItem`, **a different issue occurs**. Navigating away from the *last* list and returning via the back button shows **an empty list**.
- In all cases, the issue is resolved by swiping to the list to the left or right, and then returning.

**EDIT:**

I was wrong about the page code not being important. I'm binding in the `OnNavigatedTo` Method rather than the `MainPage` method. Romasz provided a sample which worked perfectly. I broke it by changing three parts to match my own non-working code

1. Set the page to inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged` (as I use `NotifyPropertyChanged`)
2. Moved the data-binding code to the `OnNavigatedTo` method
3. Set the `ItemsSource` of the `PivotControl` in the code-behind

With these three changes made, the sample does not work. Here's the code.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="myButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Content="Go to different Page!" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <controls:Pivot x:Name="PivotControl" Grid.Row="1" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Lists}">
            <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
            Margin="24,0,0,0" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <CheckBox></CheckBox>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                                </StackPanel>                                    
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public class myItems
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class myList
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        private List<myItems> items = new List<myItems>();
        public List<myItems> Items
        {
            get { return items; }
            set { items = value; }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<myList> _Lists;
    public ObservableCollection<myList> Lists
    {
        get
        {
            return _Lists;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Lists != value)
            {
                _Lists = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Lists");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        Lists = new ObservableCollection<myList>();

        myList list1 = new myList() { Name = "First" };
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            list1.Items.Add(new myItems() { Title = (i + 1).ToString() });

        myList list2 = new myList() { Name = "Second" };
        for (int i = 100; i < 200; i++)
            list2.Items.Add(new myItems() { Title = (i + 1).ToString() });

        myList list3 = new myList() { Name = "Third" };
        for (int i = 200; i < 300; i++)
            list3.Items.Add(new myItems() { Title = (i + 1).ToString() });

        myList list4 = new myList() { Name = "Fourth" };
        for (int i = 300; i < 400; i++)
            list4.Items.Add(new myItems() { Title = (i + 1).ToString() });

        Lists.Add(list1);
        Lists.Add(list2);
        Lists.Add(list3);
        Lists.Add(list4);

        myButton.Click += first_Click;
        this.DataContext = this;

    }

    private void first_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
}
```

Full Project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/568631/PivotProblem_2.zip

This code has a very similar issue to what I experienced. If you move to the second or third list, click on the "Go to another page" button, and then hit the back button, the pivot moves to the "first" list and shows it as empty. Navigating away and back resets the list.

If I change any one of the three differences - remove the inheritence of `INotifyPropertyChanged`, move the binding code to the MainPage or set the `ItemsSource` in the codebehind - the app works again, as expected. This has now become an academic issue (for lack of a better term) as it no longer affects my app, but I still don't know why these three factors combine to cause weird `PivotControl` behaviour

To re-iterate, changing any ONE of the factors above eliminates the issue - so what causes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, you can do something quite easy, all you need is flag

```
    bool IsDataLoaded = false; //flag

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        if (!IsDataLoaded)
        {
            Lists = new ObservableCollection<myList>();

            myList list1 = new myList() { Name = "First" };
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                list1.Items.Add(new myItems() { Title = (i + 1).ToString() });

            myList list2 = new myList() { Name = "Second" };
            for (int i = 100; i < 200; i++)
                list2.Items.Add(new myItems() { Title = (i + 1).ToString() });

            myList list3 = new myList() { Name = "Third" };
            for (int i = 200; i < 300; i++)
                list3.Items.Add(new myItems() { Title = (i + 1).ToString() });

            myList list4 = new myList() { Name = "Fourth" };
            for (int i = 300; i < 400; i++)
                list4.Items.Add(new myItems() { Title = (i + 1).ToString() });

            Lists.Add(list1);
            Lists.Add(list2);
            Lists.Add(list3);
            Lists.Add(list4);

            myButton.Click += first_Click;
            this.DataContext = this;
            IsDataLoaded = true;
        }

    }
```

OnNavigatedTo method is invoked every time when page becomes the active. That's your problem (:

Comment: If that is the problem, why does it go away when I remove `INotifyPropertyChanged`, or set the `ItemSource` from code?

Comment: because you set your `DataContext` multiple times in `OnNavigatedTo` method

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaahhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: that's an aaaaaaahhhhhh of realisation. as in aaaahhhhhh so THAT'S the reason. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Basing on your description I've built [a simple App](http://sdrv.ms/LxSfxQ). There is a Pivot with 4 Items, in each item a list with texblocks. Above the Pivot there is a button which Navigates to next Page.
I've tested such situations on it:

- scrolled the list down in First PivotItem, selected item, Navigated to Page, Back => Pivot and List rensponsive
- changed PivotItem to second, scrolled the list down, selected item, Navigated to Page, Back => Pivot and List rensponsive
- scrolled the list down in First PivotItem, changed PivotItem to second, scrolled the list down, selected item,changed PivotItem to third, scrolled the list down, selected item, Navigated to Page, Back => Pivot and List rensponsive

I couldn't reproduce your problems (emulator WP8). Can you check it? Am I missing something?

**EDIT** - after comments

In fact in the code you provided there is such an issue. For now I've managed to find out that the problems is mostly concerned with clearing Lists (or creating new Lists). I've also managed to find a little workaround ([the complete code](http://sdrv.ms/1c3Df1G)):

If I remove items in Lists except the first one (in OnNavigatedTo) and after adding new, remove the first item, then everything seems to work allright:

```
while (Lists.Count > 1)
   Lists.RemoveAt(1);
// add new items
Lists.RemoveAt(0); // watch out for the first run of OnNavigatedTo - there is a need here for if statement or something
```

I know that it doesn't answer why the problem occurs, but maybe it will help or provide a nice clue. I'll also try to work with it when I have more time.
I assume also that you need to Recreate your Lists every time you NavigateTo.

Comment: Hi Romasz. That code worked fine for me, although I had tried similar cut down apps before with no results. Upon comparing yours to mine I see three differences:
1) my page inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged
2) my binding happens in the OnNavigatedTo method. 
3) my PivotControl ItemsSource is set in XAML rather than Code

I've updated your sample app with these changes, and you can see it exhibits similar behaviour in the emulator. 

[https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/568631/PivotProblem_2.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/568631/PivotProblem_2.zip)

Comment: @roryok Now there is such an issue. I had some time, so I played with it a little - I've edited my answer, maybe you will find something useful in it.